# Sql Server Update Trigger within a Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Good day. I am trying to create an internal trigger in SQL Server. I would like the trigger to execute based off of an updated text change within a column. I would like the column change to have conditions. For example, I want the trigger to activate when the (column name) changes from `Scheduled` to `Queued` or vice versa. If the column changes to `Complete` or to another text; I don't want the trigger to occur.

My code is as follows. Thank you

```
ALTER TRIGGER [WIP].[Trigger] ON [WIP].[Roaster]
AFTER INSERT, update, delete
AS
   if update (roastprofile)
      select status 
      from wip.Roaster
      where status = 'scheduled' and status != 'Complete' and status = 'Queued'

      update controls.TriggerUpdate
      set TriggerNumber = triggernumber + 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good evening,

I was wondering about your logic.

First, you are only looking for updates, correct?
If so, remove the FOR INSERT and DELETE from the trigger definition.

Second, since you are new to triggers I left them in to teach you about the inserted and deleted tables.  A **delete** has only a non-empty deleted table and a **insert** only has a non-empty inserted table.

A update on the other hand, has both tables filled in.  The before and after value of the record sets.  I say record sets since their might be multiple records.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx

Third, please to not name the trigger the reserve word **trigger**.

Fourth, I do not understand how roastprofile comes to play.  You are just looking for updates that flip the status between two chosen pairs.  When that combination is meet, you want to update a trigger.

Last but not least, the deleted and inserted tables may have multiple records.  You will need to join them on a key value (pk).  I added a hypothetical .id that you will need to change.

Also, I saved the results of joining the records and testing for the combination into a temporary table.  This table is then queried and you trigger number is updated by the number of hits.

I do not know if this meets your business logic; however, it fixes the flaws that I saw in your design.

```
-- Delete the existing trigger.
IF EXISTS (select * from sysobjects where id = object_id('CustomCode')and type = 'TR')
   DROP TRIGGER [WIP].[CustomCode]
GO

-- Create the new trigger.
CREATE TRIGGER [WIP].[CustomCode] on [WIP].[Roaster]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE NOT FOR REPLICATION
AS

BEGIN

    -- declare local variable
    DECLARE @MYMSG VARCHAR(250);
    DECLARE @MYCNT INT;


    -- nothing to do?
    IF (@@rowcount = 0) RETURN;

    -- do not count rows
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- deleted data
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted) 
        BEGIN
            SET @MYMSG = 'DELETE ACTION'
            RETURN;
        END

    ELSE 
        BEGIN

            -- inserted data
            IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted)
            BEGIN           
                SET @MYMSG = 'INSERT ACTION'
                RETURN;
            END

            -- updated data
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @MYMSG = 'UPDATE ACTION'

                -- get the status before and after
                SELECT 
                    CASE
                        WHEN LOWER(del.status) = 'scheduled' AND LOWER(ins.status) = 'queued' THEN 1
                        WHEN LOWER(del.status) = 'queued' AND LOWER(ins.status) = 'scheduled' THEN 1
                        ELSE 0
                     END AS FLAG
                INTO 
                     #MyTemp
                FROM 
                    inserted as ins JOIN deleted as del ON ins.id = del.id;

                -- Total number of conditions satisfied
                SELECT @MYCNT = SUM(FLAG) FROM #MyTemp;

                -- your business logic
                update controls.TriggerUpdate
                set TriggerNumber = TriggerNumber + @MYCNT;


            END

            RETURN;
       END

END
GO
```

Comment: Thank you for the help and the pointers. I appreciate the constructive advise. The code works as it should for my situation. Thanks again.

Comment: Just as an aside, this is one of the nicest presentations of trigger code and showing the three possible branches that I've seen   across loads of 'how to write a trigger' examples.